# Is it possible converting a String into an audio stream to play string content?

Tags: java, javasound

I am trying to convert a string into audio stream to play the string content. Code is below.

```
public void generateSound() {
    try {

        String audioString = "hello";
        AudioInputStream inputStream=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byt.write(audioString.getBytes());
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, false, true);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(byt.toByteArray());
        AudioInputStream ais =new AudioInputStream(input, format, byt.toByteArray().length / format.getFrameSize());
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I don't know whether this is correct or not. If not what is the possible way to play the string content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not like that - but it sounds like you want a [Java Speech](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/) implementation, like [this one (FreeTTS)](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php).

Comment: We can achieve this by TTS but i dont wanna add extra jar files to my application because already too many jar files were added so my TL is not willing to accept this TTS solution. can you give me some points to play string content using javax.sound.sampled packake. it would more worthful to me thank you.

Comment: @user1023877: Assuming you really want text to speech support, and you don't want to write it yourself, there *is* no alternative. Java Sound simply doesn't support it as a feature, and I wouldn't really expect it to. (Of course this is assuming that you really *do* want text to speech. You haven't really said what you mean by "play string content.")

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet. i found 2 ways to generate sound.                       1.java itself support .wav and .au fomats so we need to write the string value to .wav file and then play it. ** for this Could you give me some points on it**.        2. We need to add FreeTTs libraries as you recommend. ** Could you tell me procedure for how to add these libraries**.

Comment: @user1023877: You don't just "write a string value to a .wav file" - you need something to "understand" how the text should sound, which is exactly what the TTS library would do. As for the "procedure for how to add these libraries" - I don't know what kind of application you're writing, or anything about it. However, the FreeTTS documentation section on "downloading and installing" seems pretty good, and there's a Quick Start section too.

Comment: IDE is Netbeans and application file is EAR (EJB + WAR) framework is jsf 1.2

Comment: sorry forgot to tell netbeans version netbeans version is 7.0.1

Comment: @user1023877: Which bit of the FreeTTS documentation did you not find clear? I may be able to help you with some specifics, but you really ought to know how to add a third-party library to your application.

Comment: i didnot start the work now. still i am doing specification part. once i am done with that then i will contact you. thank you for spending your valuable time on my Queries. today mostly i will finish the specification part then tomorrow i all contact you. thank you very much.

Comment: @user1023877: There should only be a need to reply again if you find any difficulties implementing the clear instructions which are already present in the FreeTTS project documentation.